# delete array of entities - postgres & nestjs with sequelize

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

this is my create function:

```
  async createDocument(createDocumentDto: CreateDocumentDto) {
    const request = await Document.build(<any>createDocumentDto);
    return await request.save();
  }
```

now im trying to delete the array of type CreateDocumentDto[] but i dont get from Document something like 'bulkDelete'

i've tried to do:

```
 const entities = await this.AnswersRepository.findAll(<any>deleteAnswerDto);
    if (!entities) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Something went wrong, no changes applied!`);
    }
    return this.AnswersRepository.remove(entities);
```

but i got this error:
"Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'typeof Answer'"

i can't find a solution to that. Would appreciate help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your NestJS app, don't forget to configure routes and appropriately handle requests. Using Sequelize and NestJS, this code explains how to delete documents in bulk.

In your DocumentService:

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentService {
  async createDocument(createDocumentDto: CreateDocumentDto) {
    const document = await Document.build(createDocumentDto);
    return await document.save();
  }

  async deleteDocuments(documentIds: number[]) {
    return Document.destroy({
      where: {
        id: documentIds,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

In your DocumentController:

```
@Controller('documents')
export class DocumentController {
  constructor(private readonly documentService: DocumentService) {}

  @Delete()
  async deleteDocuments(@Body() documentIds: number[]) {
    await this.documentService.deleteDocuments(documentIds);
    return 'Documents deleted';
  }
}
```